# Which DateTime module is best for manipulating an XML date and time

Tags: perl, datetime

I am trying to parse a date from a GPX (XML track format)  that looks like `2009-08-02T12:11:06Z`
My initial approach was to use [DateTime::Format::RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/~ikegami/DateTime-Format-RFC3339-v1.0.2/lib/DateTime/Format/RFC3339.pm)
But [DateTime:Format::XSD](http://search.cpan.org/~druoso/DateTime-Format-XSD-0.1/lib/DateTime/Format/XSD.pm) seems to do a similar job.

Is there a difference between the applicability of these modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DateTime:Format::XSD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-XSD/lib/DateTime/Format/XSD.pm) is just a subclass of [DateTime:Format::ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-ISO8601/lib/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pod) so you've got an extra dependency there.

But [DateTime::Format::RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-RFC3339/lib/DateTime/Format/RFC3339.pm) will not preserve your timezone (it will convert the time to UTC instead) whereas the XSD module will preserve it.

Comment: Thanks - the sort of thing I was looking for